# Unable to run Springboot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have a springboot application and am trying to run it using Run as Configuration with the goal spring-boot: run

But i get the following error 
Could not find goal '' in plugin org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.7.RELEASE among available goals build-info, help, repackage, run, start, stop -> [Help 1]

I updated the spring boot maven plugin to include goal.

```
<plugins>
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
     <execution>
        <goals>
           <goal>repackage</goal>
        </goals>
     </execution>
  </executions>
```

Comment: Please post your full error stack trace.

Comment: Did you really put "spring-boot: run" in the goal (with the space between : and run)? If yes, remove the space and try again. If not, then please add more information about your configuration and error.

Comment: Please add more info about the error, maybe the full stack trace?

Comment: Thank you @dunni .... The space is what caused the problem